# "Request cookies" vs cookies

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, cookies, webkit, session-cookies

In my project, I use [`XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials) for authentication. Now, on a regular desktop browser this understandably sets a cookie to be passed on every request to the appropriate domain. Good.

Now, since my project is a cordova app, and cordova web views supposedly don't have cookies, I'm trying to wrap my head around how this works. When I run my app and inspect the app's WebView through Chrome, I see that there are no Local File cookies, as expected, with a message on the inspector saying "By default cookies are disabled for local files. You could override this by starting the browser with --enable-file-cookies command like flag.".

Except when I do a a request to my domain, the browser *does* in fact send the right cookie through a "request cookie". It looks like this in Chrome Inspector:  [image: Request cookie on chrome inspector]

So I'm trying to figure out.

1. How does this even work if cordova is supposed to not have cookies?
2. What is the difference between regular cookies and these Request Cookies?